# Sphinx RST ERROR: Undefined substitution referenced: "$". in table

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am writing a sphinx rst table and one of the cells contains a certain symbol that errors.

Here is an example:

```
+--------+---------+
| Test   | Field   |
+--------+---------+
| |$|    | Errors  |
+--------+---------+
```

This results in `ERROR: Undefined substitution referenced: "$".`, even though this is the symbol I want in my table. It still shows up in the resulting documentation though.

Answer (score 2):

`|x|` is recognized as a [substitution reference](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#substitution-references), using `\` to escape it should work for you.

```
+--------+---------+
| Test   | Field   |
+--------+---------+
| \|$|   | Errors  |
+--------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was to simply surround `|&|` with two backticks:

```
``|$|``
```

It does make the text monospace, but it doesn't bother me. I no longer have the error in my console.